# VB.NET, How to improve (speed) for loop In Byte Array?

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, performance, for-loop

I'm here want to make own LZSS algorithm(LZSS Is Compression algorithm). But the problem is speed. When I try to compress file that have 3 MB file, the process is very very long time!

After that, I research what can make long time, and I found that when checking every bytes is very long time.
this my simple code when checking every bytes :

```
Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open)
        Dim buf(fs.Length - 1) As Byte
        fs.Read(buf, 0, fs.Length)

        Dim sise As Integer = fs.Length - 1
        Dim temp2 As Integer = 0
        Dim temp As Byte = 0
        Dim temp3 As Byte = 0

        For i = 0 To sise
            temp = buf(i)
            temp2 = i - 1
            For j = 0 To temp2

                If temp = buf(j) Then

                End If
            Next

        Next
```

When I run and open file with 27.3 KB and take 495 ms, how when I open file 20 MB and will take many minute even hours.

So, what solution, this simple code but take very many time..??

Comment: Your for loop has running complexity of `O(N^2)` where N is 20 million. Obviously it will take many many minutes.

Comment: yes, I know it, but however the algorithm lzss is like that.
example :
samuelrickysamuelrickysaputro
after compress : 
samuelrickysaputro(11,11,11)
11,11,11 because (index of char that remove,index of char that same, length char that same)
to do this, I must make many for loop.

Comment: If you are trying to find out if there are duplicate bytes: You can sort bytes array and then do a linear scan, comparing elements next to each other if they are the same. In that case complexity would be `O(NlogN)`.

Comment: @mostruash no cannot, because the LZSS is search the same pattern of byte, like ex :
byte() = (34,23,55,34,57,84,34,23,55)
the same pattern is (34,23,55)

Answer (score 0):

Your way of doing data compression is not feasible because of its time complexity `O(N*N*M)` where N is the data size and M is the maximum pattern size which is N in your case. You need to change your approach.

For example, [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/algorithm.txt) limits distance to original text to 32K and limits maximum length of a pattern to 258 bytes. In that case, time complexity of your algorithm is reduced to `O(N*32K*258)` in the worst case.

Obviously that is not fast enough. The worst case still takes too long to run. Maybe you should take a look at [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/algorithm.txt) and decide if it's worth to come up with a new data compression algorithm or if you are competent to do so.

Comment: Depending on your code, you could possibly look into a Parallel.For loop to multithread the loop so that it uses more than just one core of your processor